# What can I use to seal black cast iron pipes and fittings I'm using for handles for an outdoor cabinet so it won't rust?

Tags: sealing, cast-iron

Making an outdoor cooler enclosure using black cast iron for the handles and would like to inhibit rust from starting. What can I use to seal it?

Comment: Paint is usually the go to thing.  Using it as handles might require repainting more often, so making the handles easy to take off is an idea.

Comment: almost noting will stop cast iron from rusting

Comment: @Ruskes  nothing

Comment: @JACK ALMOST....

Comment: @Ruskes  the spelling....

Comment: @JACK forgive me, my spelling is a mixture of Italian, German and French, while my spellchecker has given up on me

Comment: @Ruskes  Sometimes wish I had that excuse for typos, it is a lot better than just not knowing the spelling in your own language.

Answer (score 1):

Linseed (== flaxseed) oil and an oven.

Season it like a cast iron pan.

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/647/34242

Or paint it, but with paint you're not really going to have the appearance of cast iron, it will just be painted pipe. A proper coat of seasoning is fairly durable and in the non-cooking sense a standard blacksmith finish for black iron/steel.

Nitpickily, polymerized linseed oil (which heating it promotes) is the basis (or at least the original basis) of most oil paints. So it's rather like painting it, effect-wise.

Comment: Guess that is what is called thinking outside of the box.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea! I wonder how often it would have to be refreshed, though. I know that cast iron cookware needs to be reseasoned somewhat regularly, and it's never washed. I wonder if rain water would wash away the seasoning (even though there's no dish soap).

Answer (score 0):

Paint it with POR-15, then a topcoat paint over that to protect the POR-15 from UV exposure.